# How to attach DBF file in Access programmatically?

Tags: c#, ms-access, dbf

Access can open DBF (dBase) files, but instead of physically converting the data into MDB format, it has the ability to link to the DBF table itself. This way the DBF is "linked" to the MDB.

Is it possible to attach a DBF file in such manner using C#?

**Edit**: I would like to use Jet and avoid using MS Access directly.

Comment: By attach do you mean setup a linked table relationship or something of that sort?

Comment: Yes, so that the DBF file is linked to MDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this code from [How to quickly copy tables from an ODBC source to MS Access within a C# project](http://cookingwithcsharp.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-quickly-copy-tables-from-odbc.html) might help:

> The VB function you’ll need to put
>   into MS Access is quite simple, and
>   basically calls the TransferDatabase
>   method by passing it a DSN (pointing
>   to the source database), a source
>   table name and target table name. The
>   code is as follows:

```
Public Function Import(dsnName As String, sourceTableName As String, targetTableName As String)
‘ if the table already existsm, delete it.
   On Error GoTo CopyTable
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, targetTableName
CopyTable:
   DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
   acImport, _
   "ODBC Database", _
   "ODBC;DSN=" + dsnName, _
   acTable, _
   sourceTableName, _
   targetTableName
End Function
```

Changing the VBA to read acLink rather than acImport should allow linking.

> And then the C# code:

```
object accessObject = null;
try
{
   accessObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Access.Application"));

   accessObject.GetType().InvokeMember(
      "OpenCurrentDatabase",
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
      null,
      accessObject,
      new Object[] { "AccessDbase.mdb" });

   accessObject.GetType().InvokeMember(
      "Run",
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
      null,
      accessObject,
      new Object[] { "Import", "DSN Name", "Source table name", "Target table name" });

   accessObject.GetType().InvokeMember(
      "CloseCurrentDatabase",
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
      null,
      accessObject,
      null);

   MessageBox.Show("Copy succeeded.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   string message = ex.Message;
   while (ex.InnerException != null)
   {
      ex = ex.InnerException;
      message += "\r\n----\r\n" + ex.Message;
   }
   MessageBox.Show(message);
}
finally
{
   if (accessObject != null)
   {
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(accessObject);
      accessObject = null;
   }
}
```

**Edit re comments**

I cannot help with c#, but here is some VBScript that links a table from
one MDB to another.

```
strLinkFile = "C:\Docs\Link.mdb"
strAccessFile = "C:\Docs\LTD.mdb"

'Create Link... '
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" & strAccessFile & ";" & _
       "Persist Security Info=False"

Set adoCat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Set adoCat.ActiveConnection = cn

Set adoTbl = CreateObject("ADOX.Table")

Set adoTbl.ParentCatalog = adoCat
adoTbl.Name = "LinkTable"

adoTbl.properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = strLinkFile
adoTbl.properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = "MS Access"
adoTbl.properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = "Table1"
adoTbl.properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True

'Append the table to the tables collection '
adoCat.Tables.Append adoTbl
```

It is modified from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240222

Comment: So, correctly me if I'm wrong, this would require Access to be present and Access automation libraries to be present.
Is it possible to achieve linking w/o use of Access?

Comment: Yes. I would like to avoid using the Access app itself - users of my code may not necessarily have it installed, and Jet is pretty much ubiquitous.

Comment: I have added some script that uses Jet.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a suggestion, but what about linking to a DBF from Access, then look at the connect string Access uses to get to the data. For this to work with Jet alone, you'll have to have the ISAM that Access uses for accessing xBase data. I don't know for certain if that's an Access component or a Jet component, though.

This is what I get for the connect string when I link to a DBF with Access 97 (and the results are identical with Access 2003):

```
dBase IV;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Path
```

In the MSysObjects table, that's in the CONNECT column and the dbf file name is in the DATABASE column. Links to Jet data have nothing in the CONNECT column and only in the DATABASE column, but the .Connect property of a tabledef that is a link to a Jet table in another MDB is the same as what's in the Database column.

So, I'm not sure exactly what you'd supply as your connect string, but [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/?carrier=dbffoxpro) has suggestions. However, those don't use Jet for accessing the data, so I'm just not sure what you would use.